# How to store HTML id as a js variable?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, getelementbyid, onmouseover

I am writing a webpage that will have 200+ links per page. Each link has a unique id that matches an id in another frame. I want to run a onmouseover function that will change the text color of both links across frames. Here's what I've got so far.

```
<html><head><title>Test</title>
  <script>
    function hey()
      {var id=//HELP PLEASE; document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";} 
    function bye()
      {var id=//HELP PLEASE; document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";}
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
 <a id="1" class="word" onmouseover="hey()" onmouseout="bye()">hello</a> 
 <a id="2" class="word" onmouseover="hey()" onmouseout="bye()">world</a>....
</body></html>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: BTW. My problem is that I'm not sure how to get the link id stored as a js variable.

Comment: you just did it in your code... document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red"; should work

Comment: You may already know this, but your comment is blocking out the end brackets of your `hey` and `bye` functions

Comment: Yeah, I just threw that bit in to show where I was having problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the id into the function:

```
<html><head><title>Test</title>
  <script>
    function hey(id)
      {document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";} 
    function bye(id)
      {document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";}
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
 <a id="1" class="word" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">hello</a> 
 <a id="2" class="word" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">world</a>....
</body></html>
```